# Optocouplers for comparator as current detector

Tags: operational-amplifier, opto-isolator, flipflop, orcad, over-current

I'm working on the realization of overcurrent detection that will be powered by a battery supply. I successfully simulated a comparator with an operational amplifier that will set the output high when there is overcurrent and the flip-flop circuit has to carry that value (until the reset button is pressed) and send it to the buffer that will set the MOSFET transistor on/off.

[image: Overcurrent protection]

Is there any way to implement into the schematic an **optocoupler** with button that will reset the flip-flop logic? Currently, I only have a V-pulse source that will reset the flip-flop every 35 ms periodically.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Simulation]

Comment: There are likely multiple ways. But you likely don't do much with that. Ask a question you want an answer. Also mention what is preventing you from putting an optocoupler there? And why does it have to be an optocoupler instead of button directly?

Comment: @Justme I want to have an optocoupler there for safety reasons. Is there any way to simulate the reset button connected to the optocoupler in OrCAD?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "safety"? What do you want to protect against?

Comment: Please read the datasheet for the LF412 op-amp, with attention to the guaranteed input common mode range.

Comment: It makes more sense to me to perform the isolation at the shunt rather than at the button. Plus your isolation scheme would require a second isolated power source to add any real protection.